# click handler in capty plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying this JS code in [jquery capty plugin](http://www.wbotelhos.com/capty/) . However the plugin needs an image to works, like:

```
<img id="default1" src="img/1.jpg" name="#content-target1" width="208" height="143" class="latest_img" />
```

Well, when i add this image the JS below didn't works. Basically what i want is just click in span and show an alert message with the content.

```
$('.tag_content').live('click', function(event){
    var span_val = $(this).parent().children("span").html();
    alert(span_val);
    });
```

**html code**

```
<div class="images">
     <a href="#"> <img id="default1" src="img/1.jpg" name="#content-target1" width="208" height="143" class="latest_img" /> </a>
     <div id="content-target1">
     <span class="tag_content">Design</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to work for me. You can try it out on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZSGt/4/

```
$('#default1').capty();
$('.tag_content').click(function() { 
    //var span_val = $(this).parent().children("span").html();
    var span_val = $(this).html();
    alert(span_val);
});
```

I also changed `$(this).parent().children("span").html()` to `$(this).html()` because it seems to be unnecessary for your code.

Comment: yes, works perfectly. I thought that i needed .live for my case. Apparently not. Thanks